# jQuery Waypoints and Changing Nav Class

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using Waypoints.js and have a question about changing the style of a nav item when a certain waypoint is reached. I'm using this code to add a class of black to the menu item menu-item-29 when the waypoint post-26 is reached. It works, however when you scroll away off the waypoint, the black class isn't removed (it stays). How can I remove the black class when the waypoint is scrolled away? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".post-26").waypoint(function () {
$('#menu-item-29').addClass('black');
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The waypoint function is passed a `direction` parameter. Use that to determine whether you should add or remove.

```
$('.post-26').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
    $('#menu-item-29').addClass('black');
  }
  else {
    $('#menu-item-29').removeClass('black');
  }
});
```

Or, since jQuery's `toggleClass` takes a second boolean parameter indicating whether to add or remove, you can just write it like this:

```
$('.post-26').waypoint(function(direction) {
  $('#menu-item-29').toggleClass('black', direction === 'down');
});
```

Comment: I just realized that I never thanked you for this... thank you, it worked brilliantly.

Comment: Care to explain with do we need direction === down ? What if we are using anchor a links, or if we scroll up, shouldn't that class be removed as well. This is quite a basic javascript question but, how can we do something, on this case, "remove the class", whenever the function IS NOT the case?

Comment: @MEM The second argument to jQuery's `toggleClass` is a boolean. If it is true, it adds the class. If it is false, it removes the class. If it is omitted, it toggles.